# Make slider divs the same height. AJAX is interfering with this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a slider that I have created for a Wordpress site and I am having an issue. I have some jQuery that resizes the slide's div to fill the screen. The problem is that they plugin I am using does not load all of the slides initially - it loads them with an AJAX call. So, since my jQuery is on `$(document).load()` it is not working. The first slide looks as it should, but the following slides to not fill the height of the screen. Is there any way to resize all of the divs even if they are not loaded into the DOM?

I tried to accomplish this by running a function on every AJAX success, but you can see the slide's div resize and it doesn't look very nice.

Here is my jQuery:

`height = $(window).height();
$('.et_pb_slide').height(height - 70);`

Here is the `div` in question:

`<div class="et_pb_slide et_pb_bg_layout_dark et_pb_media_alignment_center et-pb-active-slide" style='background-image:url(http://takethecity.dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/columbus_bw.jpg)'>`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot target elements that do not exist in your DOM.

How about doing the required re-sizing once the ajax call has completed? If you don't like the "animation" hide the element before you resize it, and show it once the resizing is complete.

```
$.ajax({
 ....,
 success: function(){
    //do your stuff here.
  }
});
```

Comment: There are a couple of issues with that. I do not have direct access to the AJAX call because it is a plugin. Also, I am using a slide animation, so hiding it and then resizing it would not allow the slide animation to look that smooth.

Comment: You can always tap into the global ajax success method. https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/. You can also do the following: have your container fill the entire height you need with relative position. Place your slides inside of this container with height: 100%. It will not work in older browsers, but this way you can force the size of your slides. If you can create a fiddle with your code I can take a look at it for you.